# PHP - <a href> leading to "Cannot modify header information"

Tags: php, header

I really need some help with this issue, I've been looking everywhere however there seems to be no fix that relates to me.

This is even more so frustrating as it was working perfectly fine just 10 minutes ago and now the whole website does not work.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/projectspace/cicrpuiy/internal/content/heading_navigation.php:37)

However, upon looking up line 37 of "heading_navigation.php"

```
<?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) { // end user is logged in if

            ?>
                <a href="index.php?page=../admin/newentry" title="Add a new entry"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
```

The <a href </a line is line 37 which is not even included in the php block, I do not understand what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: This means that at line 37 you have any type of output (e.g. you are printing `<a href`) and then afterwards you have a function that is trying to edit the response headers. For example you have `session_start` or `header` function to make a redirect. All these functions need to be called BEFORE any other output as they edit the header of your server response

Comment: _line 37 which is not even included in the php block_ The a tag prints when your if condition is true and does not when the if condition is false.